# PostgreSQL: Select only past three months of data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select only the past three months of data from a table. I've attempted the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM cte_data
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, my_timestamp, GETDATE()) <= 3
```

This is returning the error:
**ERROR: column "month" does not exist Position: 1182**

My date follows the format:
**December 16, 2021, 2:40 PM**

How can I make this work?

NOTE: I'm using PostgreSQL on Metabase.

Comment: getdate() smells like ms sql server. postgres has now()

Comment: @LukStorms: Postgres also doesn't have a `datediff()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), there is no `datediff()`  function in Postgres. You just subtract an `interval`:

```
select *
from cte_data
where my_timestamp >= current_timestamp - interval '3 month';
```